# Reload all modules in a directory

Tags: python, import, module, directory, reload

I need to reload all the python modules within a specified directory.

I've tried something like this:

```
import sys, os
import_folder = "C:\\myFolder"
sys.path.insert( 0 , import_folder )
for dir in os.listdir(import_folder):
    name = os.path.splitext(dir)[0]
    ext = os.path.splitext(dir)[1]
    if ext == ".py":
        import( eval(name) )
        reload( eval(name) )
```

Anyone know how to do this correctly?

Comment: "I need to reload all the python modules within a specified directory." – Why?

Comment: One case where somebody would want to reload all the modules in the directory might be when the output is time-dependent. Say for example, if the program gets the data from the database which is regularly been updated and user modules are not linked within themselves, reloading all the modules in particular directory can come handy.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades: There point is that there is probably a better solution to the OP's problem, so we need to know what this problem actually is.  BTW, I don't understand the use case you described.

Comment: The case I am describing is: If I write a program to get the data from the last row from the database which is constantly updated. One way to do this ( I know this is a crude and rough way and think this is similar to what OP is intending to do) is write the program that connects it to the database and gets the data and secondly write a program to reload that module in regular interval of time.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades then why don't you simply do a function and call it instead of reloading the module? It makes no sense... "Simple is better than complex."

Comment: My guess is that he is trying to add a Plugin feature into his program

Comment: The reason: I am writing tools/plugins for a 3D application (Softimage/Xsi). When this program is first launched it loads all the modules in a "\\server\modules" folder into memory. I work in a "\\server\modules_dev" folder and the once I'm done editing a module I copy it accross to "\\server\modules". The only way to get the 3D application to reload the modules while its running is to call "reload(module_name)". I want to create a button that the users can click that will reload all the modules in "\\server\modules" once I'm done copying them accross from "\\server\modules_dev".

Comment: @JaredGlass: you *can't* safely do it. Partial solutions can be made, but they all have inherent flaws which cannot possibly be resolved.

Comment: "... how to do this correctly?" *Don't.* Restart your entire program.

Comment: Restarting the program can take well over an hour. Any hack or fix would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os # we use os.path.join, os.path.basename
import sys # we use sys.path
import glob # we use glob.glob
import importlib # we use importlib.import_module

import_folder = 'C:\\myFolder'
sys.path.append(import_folder) # this tells python to look in `import_folder` for imports
for src_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(import_folder, '*.py')):
    name = os.path.basename(src_file)[:-3]
    importlib.import_module(name)
    reload(sys.modules[name])
    importlib.import_module(name)
```

There is the code. Now to the semantics of the whole thing: using [importlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) makes this a little bit more normal, but it still promotes some bugs. You can see that this breaks for source files in a subdirectory. What you should probably do is: import the package, (import the whole folder), and use the `.` operator like so:

```
import sys # we use sys.path
sys.path.append('C:\\')
import myFolder
...
myFolder.func1(foo)
myFolder.val
bar = myFolder.Class1()
```

Perhaps you should take a look at the [documentation for modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages), but don't forget to update the path to include the parent of the folder you want to import.